# PHP: Shuffle array, so no value is like the correspondent one

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

There is an array with names, for example:

$donalds_nephews = array('Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie');

```
array
(
    [0] => Huey
    [1] => Dewey
    [2] => Louie
)
```

I want to shuffle this array, but ensure that no value of the original array has the same key as the shuffled one.

```
$donalds_nephews_shuffled = shuffle($donalds_nephews);
```

This could result in 6 possible permutations:

1. **Huey**, Dewey, Louie
2. **Huey**, Louie, Dewey
3. Dewey, Louie, Huey
4. Dewey, Huey, **Louie**
5. Louie, **Dewey**, Huey
6. Louie, Huey, Dewey

1st, 2nd, 4th and 5th must not be the result.

What's the best way to do so? It's for Secret Santa.

Comment: put the last element as first and skip all the others by one. But why you want to do this?

Comment: Shift it one over, problem solved. Shuffling means random. What you want isn't random. What exactly do you need?

Comment: Each one has to make a gift to someone else. Secret Santa!

Comment: Try creating another array thats 2 demensional to store all the values and indexes that already happened in the shuffle use it in an if statement and nested for loops.

Comment: I need random, actually the array is much greater.

Comment: Are you looking for permutations of an array. a function can be found here: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch04_26.htm

Comment: So you need a dynamic array for the already happened values? If so then maybe an arraylist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shuffle the original array, then make a copy of it and shift all entries one over, then match the two back together to get your matches.

Comment: That sounds clever. What would be the best way to shift all values one over?

Comment: @Ben `$array[] = array_shift($array);`

Comment: Oh, great. I was thinking of a for loop. Is `$array = array_shift($array);` wihout brackets also okay?

Comment: @Ben No, that's not the same thing.

Comment: Additionally, what, if I have a list of 2-tuples containing names of persons, who should not be Secret Santa partners, because they dislike each other? That makes it complicated, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, that makes it pretty complicated. Then you pretty much have to loop through all names, prepare an array of possible candidates for each name which does not include himself or people he dislikes, choose a random one, remove the choice from the global pool and repeat. That of course may get you into a deadlock where some don't get any partner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. To avoid a deadlock was actually my problem while trying.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to avoid a deadlock?

Comment: @Ben Nope. Seems like a nice involved mathematical problem. No idea if there's even a solution to it. I'd try a new question, possibly even on one of the more theoretical/mathematical sites.

Comment: Last question: how would you match the two arrays back together?

Comment: @Ben Depends on what the result should look like. `array_combine($array1, $array2)` or `array_map(null, $array1, $array2)` would be my guess.

Answer (score 1):

> It's for Secret Santa.

Then start with a better algorithm. Currently you seem to be inferring that the key is a present giver and the value a present receiver (or vice versa). This then entails the additional check (and possible re-iteration of the shuffling) to ensure that nobody ends up giving a present to themselves.

But what if you just consider it as an ordered list of names, such that each entry gives to the next person on the list:

```
$victims=array('Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie');
shuffle($victims);
$giver='';
foreach($victims as $receiver) {
  if ($giver) print "$giver gives to $receiver\n";
  $giver=$receiver;
}
$receiver=array_shift($victims);
print "$giver gives to $receiver\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

just cause i need this for my secret santa :)

```
<?php

    function compareArrays($original, $shuffled){   
        for($i = 0; $i < count($original); $i++ ){
            if($original[$i] == $shuffled[$i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    $donalds_nephews = array('Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie','Igor','Stephan');

    //avoid loops
    for($j = 0; $j < 50; $j++){
        $shuffled = $donalds_nephews;
        shuffle($shuffled);
        $good = compareArrays($donalds_nephews, $shuffled);

        if($good) break;
    }

    if($good){
        echo "here we go!\n";
        foreach($shuffled as $k => $v){
            echo "$k => $v \n";
        }
    }
    else { 
        echo "try again \n";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't make this complicated by trying to put all of this into one function.

Here's your pseudocode:

```
$givers  = array( 'Huey', 'Dewey', 'Louie' );
$getters = $givers;

foreach ( $givers as $giver ) {
    do {
        pick a random $getter from $getters;
    } until $getter <> $giver;
    delete $getter from $getters;
    print "$giver gives to $getter\n";
}
```

Comment: That's a very non-deterministic algorithm and may possibly never finish in the worst case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but you asked for the best way, so how about this?

```
function santaYates($array) {
    $returnArray = array_values($array); // Cause we need a clean numeric array
    $secure = false;
    for($i = count($returnArray) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $r = mt_rand(0, $i-1); //subtract 1 from $i to force a new place.
        $tmp = $returnArray[$i];
        $returnArray[$i] = $returnArray[$r];
        $returnArray[$r] = $tmp;
    }

    return $returnArray;
}
```

It works very similar to the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

There is just one little difference:
We permit to use the same key, so every entry will get a new place (cause we substract 1 from $i when we do the randomize step).

[Working Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c7c115b6f4a87e3367ff2eb9ade07d00495155e)