# Shuffle PHP array, guaranteeing each has a different key

Tags: php, shuffle

I'm building a gift exchange website, where people put in their emails, and then each of the entrants is matched with another entrant (the sender). I'm using PHP (probably Symfony, if it makes a difference).

I'm expecting the number of entrants to be around 600-800, and this will be run quite frequently.

I thought I could use `shuffle()` and `array_combine()` on the array of recipients to do this. 
However, after the `shuffle()` the sender could still be in the same position, so would have to *give a Secret Santa present to themselves*.

For example:

```
$recipients = "SQL query that returns array"
# ['bob', 'alice', 'joe']

$senders = $recipients; 
shuffle($senders);
# ['alice', 'bob', 'joe']

$result = array_combine($recipients, $senders);
# ['bob' => 'alice', 'alice' = 'bob', 'joe' => 'joe']
```

So I need to guarantee that in the final array, none of the values equal the key. So far, I have thought of the following possible solutions but they all seem expensive and a bit rubbish:

1. Use `array_walk()` over the final array. Put any values into another array, then swap them with each other afterwards. If there's only 1, just swap it with anything.
2. Take all the values from the `$recipients` array that have even keys, and all the values from the `$senders` array that have odd keys. Shuffle both of those arrays.
3. Instead of using `shuffle()` implement my own crappy version that does something like shift all the values forward two, and then do `array_reverse()`.
4. Loop through recipients, and use `array_rand()` to pick an item from `$senders`. If it's the same, pick again, otherwise remove it from the array, set it the be the sender for that recipient, and move on to the next recipient.

Perhaps I'm overthinking this - is there a simpler way? Or is there a special way of doing this in PHP that I don't know about?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - Make an associative array unique, key -> value and value -> key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040084/php-make-an-associative-array-unique-key-value-and-value-key)

Comment: @Dagon that question is asking about removing duplicate key-value pairs from an associative array. In this question, I'm not trying to remove duplicates, I'm trying to prevent `shuffle()` producing an array where the key equals the value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. shuffle
2. create a copy
3. perform a circular shift
4. combine

   ```
   $users = array('bob', 'alice', 'joe');

   shuffle($users);

   $santas = $users;
   $santas[] = array_shift($santas);

   $result = array_combine($santas, $users);

   var_dump($result);
   ```

Demo: http://codepad.org/jxrzczRG

Comment: What do you mean by a circular shift?

Comment: @Blowski Imagine your array as a rolling disk, so when you move your array one position forward, the last element takes the first position, the first element takes the second position, so on and so forth.

Comment: Oh just read, I think I understand. `shuffle()` the array, and then do a simple version of solution #3

Comment: @zerkms been thinking about this, and there's still no guarantee that in the resulting array, no user will equal the relevant santa. They could be in different positions before the circular shift, and then in the same position after.

Comment: @Blowski: there is guarantee for that. As soon as there are more than 2 people in total - after a circular shift they will **ALWAYS** be different. If you still think I'm wrong - try to provide the *shuffled `$users`* array that proves your point.

Comment: @zerkms Sorry, I didn't actually do the code and I realise now that you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a similar code to the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```
function santaYates($array) {
    $keys = array_keys($array); //Store the keys
    $values = array_values($array); // Cause we need a clean numeric array for this kind of randomisation
    $secure = false;
    for($i = count($values) - 1; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $r = mt_rand(0, $i-1); //subtract 1 from $i to force a new place.
        $tmp = $values[$i];
        $values[$i] = $values[$r];
        $values[$r] = $tmp;
    }
    $returnArray = array_combine($keys, $values); //Now recombine keys and values
    return $returnArray;
}
```

I wrote this code for [answering a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13849677/php-shuffle-array-so-no-value-is-like-the-correspondent-one) but this version can also handle associative arrays.
You can [Test this version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a0ed105b14f810a32b75ca177f42f3e34f869a85)